# nextLevel function won't execute upon click event on the LeftSide's last child

Tags: javascript, html, dom, event-handling, dom-events

EDIT: Let me explain what the project is. I have to make a game in which the player has to click on the face on the left side that is not present on the right side; the extra face basically. I can make everything populate just fine so far, but when I click on the extra face, the nextLevel function doesn't execute.

EDIT: Also, keep in mind that the generateFaces function executes for the first time onLoad in the HTML (not shown).

The function, nextLevel, won't execute when I click on the extra face on the left side (which would be theleftSide.lastChild). It just goes straight to the gameOver function instead, which is supposed to execute if you click anywhere else on the body. My code:

```
    let numberOfFaces = 5;
    const theLeftSide = document.querySelector('#leftSide');
    const theRightSide = document.querySelector('#rightSide');

    function generateFaces() {
        for (let i = 0; i < numberOfFaces; i++) {
            const face = document.createElement('img');
            face.src = 'images/smile.png';

            let randomTop = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 1;
            let randomLeft = Math.floor(Math.random() * 400) + 1;
            face.style.top = randomTop + 'px';
            face.style.left = randomLeft + 'px';
            theLeftSide.appendChild(face);
        }

        const leftSideImages = theLeftSide.cloneNode(true);
        leftSideImages.removeChild(leftSideImages.lastChild);
        theRightSide.appendChild(leftSideImages);

        theLeftSide.lastChild.addEventListener('click', nextLevel);

        document.body.addEventListener('click', gameOver);
    }

    function nextLevel(event) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        numberOfFaces += 5;
        
        generateFaces();
    }

    function gameOver() {
        alert('Game Over!');
        // theLeftSide.lastChild.removeEventListener('click', nextLevel);
        // document.body.removeEventListener('click', gameOver);
    }
```

I've gone through the entire code as well as my instructions for the project multiple times, but I still can't seem to figure out what's wrong. It appears I have followed all instructions properly.

Is the event listener not in the correct place?

Any help would be super appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I realize it's probably some small thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered that it's an issue with Chrome. Everything works fine in other browsers including Chrome Portable. It may be an extension I'm running. I'll have to troubleshoot this later. But anyway, it appears my code now works. Thanks to the person who answered. :)